# Wordpress Front Page Structure

Tags: html, wordpress, seo, content-management-system

I was making a site using wordpress. I decided that i wanted to have a static front page, without blog posts and stuff. Consequently i added an image slider and a selection of widgets with text underneath it.

My problem is that my page, which is considered the front page, has bad SEO. I tried to write few words but i really want the slider in the place instead and nothing more there.

My structure is as follows:

```
{text:call-us}{text:an intro sentence}{icon:facebook}

{image:logo}{menu}

{slider with captions}

{text: about the site as widget (not via page creation)}

{text:couple words with font awesome}

{text: more text} {text: more text}

{footer:map}{footer:facebook}{footer:contact}
```

So, how can i handle the need of wordpress to write something in a page so vital, that is not visible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Create your page in Wordpress, define it as homepage in the Reading section of the admin settings, create a template-home.php (or whatever name) in your theme folder and put inside it:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home page
*/
get_header();
?>

<!-- Put your static content here -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Edit your home page in WP back office, then select "Home page" as your page template. No need to put the doctype / head, worpress will handle that for you with `get_header`.

Comment: The home page template should be named **front-page.php** or **home.php**, so that it is automatically applied to the home page (rather than having to select a template in the Admin): https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/